# ColdSpring IsLazyInit isn't boolean?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldspring

Anyone ever seen this error with ColdSpring?

> The ISLAZYINIT argument passed to the createBeanDefinition function is not of type boolean.

This is happening after restarting the CF service, and when it's attempting to do something like this in onApplicationStart

```
beanFactory = createObject("coldspring.beans.DefaultXmlBeanFactory").init(defaultProperties=stuCsConfig);
beanFactory.loadBeans(expandPath("/shared/config/coldspring-services.xml"));
```

The contents of that coldspring-services.xml file looks something like:

```
<bean id="PageHeader" class="path.to.PageHeader" singleton="true" lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg name="fooBar">
        <value>${fooBar}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

for a few dozen similarly constructed beans, some set to `lazy-init=false`, some set to `lazy-init=true`.

Nothing particularly obvious in the code has changed recently, and I'm wondering if it's possibly a problem with the Java JVM, or something that could be set in CF Admin such as caching.  Anyone seen this before or has a suggestion?

Comment: Do you use hyphen's in other attributes? I'm assuming that coldspring is stripping out the hyphen when examining the attribute right?

Comment: ColdSpring converts the lazy-init attribute (if it's defined) to isLazyInit deep inside the DefaultXmlBeanFactory, see https://github.com/wolfnet/coldspring/blob/master/beans/DefaultXmlBeanFactory.cfc#L312  I don't think the fact it has a hyphen would be the problem. This code has been working fine for a long while, it's only on one server we were deploying a new release to that it's started throwing this error

Comment: I vaguely remember having this issue before. However, IIRC I solved this by deleting the cached java classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be this: on that server Java had been upgraded from 7 to 8.  It hadn't worked, so it was rolled back to Java 7.  However it seems that something was changed by the upgrade that hadn't been reverted when it was changed back to Java 7.

The fix was to completely uninstall Java and re-install v7 from start, which seemed to fix it.